# How to add list elements from Admin form to User form using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to add the list elements dynamically to User form from the Admin form. But I am unable to do that. Can anyone help me on this.

**User.html Page Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="dynamic-list"></ul>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Admin.html Page Code:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Admin Page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="candidate"/>
    <button onclick="addItem()">add item</button>
    <button onclick="removeItem()">remove item</button>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
function addItem(){
var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
var li = document.createElement("li");
li.setAttribute('id',candidate.value);
li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(candidate.value));
ul.appendChild(li);
}

function removeItem(){
var ul = document.getElementById("dynamic-list");
var candidate = document.getElementById("candidate");
var item = document.getElementById(candidate.value);
ul.removeChild(item);
}
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do.  Which page is currently being displayed?  How are you looking to access the other page at that time?  Why do you need to access that page?  What's the goal?

Comment: I want to show the list elements in the User form. Those list elements I want to add from the Admin form dynamically using javascript.

Comment: HTML does not maintain state, which is why we use cookies or sessions. When the page is navigated to the user.html, everything done on the admin.html will be lost.

Comment: But once you leave the Admin.html page and navigate to the User.html page, where did you store that data that you can access it?  Modifying the DOM in the browser doesn't actually modify the *file* on the *server*.  It sounds like you're misunderstanding a few things here.

Answer (score 0):

try setting the value to your localStorage or sessionStorage using setItem method, though not a ideal way. set that from admin page and get that item on other page , which could be simple, set on every refresh, not async , this would be simple for you for you 101 app. Also everytime before setting getItems , and maintain a id or count , so you could iterate it or compare for duplication. So on Admin something like :

```
sessionStorage.setItem('key', 'value')
```

maintain a count variable there itself

```
sessionStorage.getItem('count')
```

Though sessionStorage also give a length variable , but something like this could be used for your play around, though **I strongly suggest using API**